# Redirect after Ajax success based on response received

Tags: ajax

```
success: function(res) {
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
                            var loginResponse = obj.Result.success;
                            alert(loginResponse);
                            if(loginResponse = "true")
                            {
                                location.href = "http://www.google.com/"
                            }
                            else
                                alert("Login Failed");
                        }
                    });
```

My res will be as follows

```
{"Result":{"success":true,"userId":"ssressWRTc","dateOfFirstLogin":"2014-03-15 05:24:40"}}
```

But it always alerts "Login Failed" even if the success is True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    "Result": {
        "success": true,
            "userId": "ssressWRTc",
            "dateOfFirstLogin": "2014-03-15 05:24:40"
    }
};


var loginResponse = obj.Result.success;
alert(loginResponse);
if (loginResponse === true) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
} else alert("Login Failed");
```

Comment: I added quotes for true and missed a semi colon for redirection. That was the problem. Thanks

Comment: And always use `if (loginResponse === true)`